# How to get usernames with a tweet search query

Tags: python

I am trying to append a column to my data frame of usernames from my search query from twitter tweets. Any ideas on the code?

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key=con_key, consumer_secret=con_secret)
auth.set_access_token(acc_token, acc_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


num_needed = 1000
tweet_list = []
last_id = -1 # id of last tweet seen
while len(tweet_list) < num_needed:
    try:
        new_tweets = api.search(q = 'Python', count = 300, max_id = str(last_id - 1), lang = 'en', tweet_mode = 'extended')
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print("Error", e)
        break
    else:
        if not new_tweets:
            print("Could not find any more tweets!")
            break
        tweet_list.extend(new_tweets)
        last_id = new_tweets[-1].id

[tweet.full_text for tweet in tweet_list]
        
df = pd.DataFrame([tweet.full_text for tweet in tweet_list], columns = ['Tweets'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key=con_key, consumer_secret=con_secret)
auth.set_access_token(acc_token, acc_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


num_needed = 10
tweet_list = []
user_list = []
screen_name_list = []
last_id = -1 # id of last tweet seen
while len(tweet_list) < num_needed:
    try:
        new_tweets = api.search(q = 'Python', count = 300, max_id = str(last_id - 1), lang = 'en', tweet_mode = 'extended')
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print("Error", e)
        break
    else:
        if not new_tweets:
            print("Could not find any more tweets!")
            break
        else:
            for tweet in new_tweets:
                # fetching the screen name 

                screen_name = tweet.author.screen_name
                user_name = tweet.author.name
  
                tweet_text = tweet.full_text
                tweet_list.append(tweet_text)
                user_list.append(user_name)
                screen_name_list.append(screen_name)
        
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["tweets"] = tweet_list
df["user_name"] = user_list
df["screen_name"] = screen_name_list

df
```

Answer (score 0):

are the usernames contained in tweet.user or something like that? If so then create a second column called:

```
df['user'] = pd.Series([tweet.user for tweet in tweet_list]
```

Comment: It would be dependent on the structure of the file. Can U share an example tweet?